# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL from Ghost deployed to App Engine with Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, ghost-blog

I was following this tutorial to deploy Ghost to Google App Engine
https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ghost-on-app-engine-part-1-deploying

However, the approach of installing Ghost as an NPM Module has been deprecated.

This tutorial introduced a method of installing Ghost with a Dockerfile. https://vanlatum.dev/ghost-appengine/

I'm trying to deploy Ghost to Google App Engine by utilizing this Dockerfile, and connect to my Google Cloud SQL database.

However I'm getting the issue:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error:
[2019-10-03 21:10:46] ERROR connect ENOENT /cloudsql/ghost

connect ENOENT /cloudsql/ghost

"Unknown database error"

Error ID:
    500

Error Code:
    ENOENT

----------------------------------------

DatabaseError: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/ghost
    at DatabaseError.KnexMigrateError (/var/lib/ghost/versions/2.31.1/node_modules/knex-migrator/lib/errors.js:7:26)
```

In the first tutorial it mentions needing to run a migration before starting ghost to prevent this issue. So I've tried adding this line in my Dockerfile

```
RUN npm install knex-migrator --no-save
RUN NODE_ENV=production node_modules/knex-migrator init --mgpath node_modules/ghost
```

But then I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: node_modules/knex-migrator: Permission denied
The command '/bin/sh -c NODE_ENV=production node_modules/knex-migrator init --mgpath node_modules/ghost' returned a non-zero code: 126
```

How can I configure my Dockerfile to migrate the database before running Ghost to ensure it can connect to the Cloud SQL database?

Files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ghost

COPY config.production.json /var/lib/ghost/config.production.json
WORKDIR /var/lib/ghost
COPY credentials.json /var/lib/ghost/credentials.json
RUN npm install ghost-gcs --no-save
WORKDIR /var/lib/ghost/content/adapters/storage/ghost-gcs/
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thomas-vl/ghost-gcs/master/export.js index.js

WORKDIR /var/lib/ghost
```

config.production.json

```
{
  "url": "https://redactedurl.appspot.com",
  "fileStorage": false,
  "mail": {},
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "socketPath": "/cloudsql/ghost",
      "user": "redacted",
      "password": "redacted",
      "database": "ghost",
      "charset": "utf8"
    },
    "debug": false
  },
  "server": {
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": "2368"
  },
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "content/"
  },
  "logging": {
    "level": "info",
    "rotation": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "transports": ["file", "stdout"]
  },
  "storage": {
    "active": "ghost-gcs",
    "ghost-gcs": {
      "key": "credentials.json",
      "bucket": "redactedurl"
    }
  }
}
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
service: blog
env: flex
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
env_variables:
  MYSQL_USER: redacted
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: redacted
  MYSQL_DATABASE: ghost
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: redacted:us-central1:ghost
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: redacted:us-central1:ghost
skip_files:
  - ^(.*/)?#.*#$
  - ^(.*/)?.*~$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
  - ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
  - ^(.*/)?\..*$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.ts$
  - ^(.*/)?config\.development\.json$

``
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Connecting from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) page, you need to update your path to `/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` (so `/cloudsql/redacted:us-central1:ghost`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this still gives me the ENOENT error.

Comment: @Dayton - there are a few other steps on that page you can try. 
1. Make sure to enable the Cloud SQL Admin API. 
2. Make sure the service account running the code has the correct IAM permissions (`Cloud SQL Client` or higher).
3. If it's flex, make sure you have the config in your `app.yaml`.